# Jasperstudio задать имена отчетов

Tags: java, pdf, jasperstudio

В JasperStudio выводится отчет, таких отчетов набирается множество, они объединяются в приложении  в один файл пдф. Если просматривать во вьюверах пдф - то будет множество отчетов с одним именем , определённым в отчете в поле Report Name. Как занести в это поле какое-то имя в процессе построения пдф?